# ¿Por qué prevtab y nexttab no funcionan dentro del modal en bootstrap?

Tags: bootstrap

Actualmente estoy empleando el siguiente código:

```
<div class="card">
    <div class="card-body">
        <div class="wizard-tab mb-4">
            <ul class="nav nav-tabs d-block d-sm-flex">
                <li class="nav-item mr-auto mb-4">
                    <a class="nav-link p-0 active" data-toggle="tab" href="#tab1"> 
                        <div class="d-flex">
                            <div class="mr-3 mb-0 h1">1</div>
                        </div>

                    </a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item mr-auto mb-4">
                    <a class="nav-link p-0" data-toggle="tab" href="#tab2">                                                    
                        <div class="d-flex">
                            <div class="mr-3 mb-0 h1">2</div>
                        </div>
                    </a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="tab-content">
            <div class="tab-pane fade active show" id="tab1">
                <div class="form">
                    <p>Hola</p>
                    <button type="button" class="btn float-right btn-primary nexttab">Next</button>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="tab-pane fade" id="tab2">
                <div>
                    <p>Hola</p>
                    <div class="d-flex">
                       <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary prevtab">Previous</button>
                       <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary nexttab ml-auto">Next</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
          </div>
    </div>
 </div>
```

El **problema** es que si lo coloco dentro de un modal, no funcionan los prev y next tabs al cliquear los correspondientes botones, sin embargo, si los ubico fuera del modal funcionan perfectamente. Adjunto el modal:

```
<div class="modal" v-if="modal">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg modal-dialog-scrollable">
        <div class="modal-content">
             <!-- MODAL HEADER -->
             <!-- MODAL BODY -->
                 <div class="modal-body">
                  <!--AQUI ESTOY INCRUSTANDO EL CARD ANTERIOR DE LOS NAVS -->
                 </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS del modal:

```
.modal{
    padding-right: 14px;
    display: list-item;
    overflow: auto;
    opacity: 1;
    background: rgba(4, 5, 10, 0.8);
}
```

Así que mi pregunta es cómo lograr solucionar y hacer que funcionen los botones dentro del dialog.

Answer (score 0):

A mí me pasó algo similar, al insertar una galería en un modal.
Prueba con agregarle un `id="prevtab"` a tu botón, y que con este **id** trabaje JavaScript.

```
<button type="button" id="prevtab" class="btn btn-primary">Previous</button>
```

Si esto no te funciona, te va llevar mucho trabajo arreglando las *rutas* en tu estilo CSS; algo como: `.modal .modal-body .cars card-body .tab-pane button`.

Comment: No me funcionó con ese método :(, actualmente le tengo una solución parche que es cambiar mi v-if por v-show (ya que estoy usando Vue.js). Supongo que no es lo más óptimo, pero al menos ahí tiene el comportamiento que busco